# Database Corruption: Missing/Duplicate Records in MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access

**The Problem**

I have a VB6 application which uses Microsoft Access as the back end. The app is used in a multi-user environment. Recently, with no changes made to the application, we're seeing that in one of the tables of the database some records aren't being saved, while other records are saved twice, or some time even 3 times.

**The Details**

It's a VB6 application with Access 2002 as the back end. The app is installed in a computer running Windows 2008 Server. Multiple users on the network have a shortcut to the application on their computers and they run the application at once, accessing the same database but different records.

The application uses the following logic to save a record to the database:

```
1
If objectID > 0
  ' existing record
  sql = "UPDATE myTable SET a=..., b=..., etc WHERE Id = objectID"
  cn.Execute sql  
Else
  ' new object; create new record
  nextID = "SELECT Max(id) + 1 FROM myTable"
  sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (a,b,c) VALUES (...)"
  cn.Execute sql
  objectID = nextID
End If
Exit Function 

Err_Handler:
' handle the case where two people get the same ID
If timeNotExpired Then
   ' Try saving again;
   Resume 1
Else
   ' Could not save; display error 
End If
```

Thus when saving a record, if it exists it's UPDATED, otherwise it's INSERTED. The primary key field is obtained by calling Max(ID) + 1. With this setup, it's possible that Max(ID) + 1 may return the same ID for two users that are saving to the same table at the very same time. If this happens, the application goes back to where that label 1 is, and Max(ID) + 1 is called again until there is no conflict or until the save operation times out. Simple.

Last week, out of the blue, with no changes made to the application, it just started happening that (1) records in one table would randomly not save, or (2) a given record in that same table would show up in the database twice or even 3 times. In other words, a record in that table would appear in the database more than once.

It doesn't happen all the time but it happens a good 5-10 times a day. Please note that there are at least 5 people using the application throughout the day, mostly for data entry purposes. If a given record isn't save properly, the data gets out of sync and the application displays a message. At that point, if I check the database, I'll see that a record is either missing or duplicate. And usually, when it happens to one person, it will happen to other users who are also entering data. At the same time.

**Edit**
Let me add a bit more context... I have two tables (among others) that represent a parent/child relationship as in a customer/order scenario. A parent is required to have at least one child and the application has checks in place to ensure that a parent is not saved to the database unless the user has added at least one child for it. A user may not proceed to do anything with the application if he adds a parent without any children. The database code that saves parents (and children) has an if statement that reads something along the lines of "If parentHasNoChildren Exit Function". *There's absolutely no way, absolutely no way, abso...lutely no... way... for the application to run code which would result in a parent that is saved to the database with no children.*

But alas, starting last week, with absolutely no modifications to the application, we're seeing parents with no children left and right in the database. The problem occurs about 10 times per day, per user.

I have since modified the application so that it alerts the user when it finds a parent that has no children. If so, the program instructs them to delete the record and add it again, after which everything is fine.

Now, the fact that parents are reaching the database without children can only mean that (1) the application attempted to save the child, (2) Access returned no errors and behaved like everything was ok and (3) the application "thought everything was peachy" when in fact the child was not saved at all. And I know Access returned no error because **the application logs every error that occurs during save operations. I checked the logs and there are no errors about children not being saved.**

---

**Edit 2: (I believe I found the problem!)**

Upon inspection of the database, I just discovered that the primary key in the child table is gone. That is, the field that is supposed to be set as the primary key is there, but it isn't set as the primary key. I have no idea how this happened. The database design hasn't been touched so I'm assuming MS Access woke up one day and said "hmm, I wonder what would happen if I deleted the primary key from this table..."

In any event, I believe this is definitely the cause of my problem. The primary key was set up to prevent duplicate entries. With the key gone, it's possible to save two child records with the same ID. Since my code uses Max(ID) +1 to generate the ID for new child records, it's possible that Max (ID) +1 would return the same ID for multiple users that attempt to save a child record at the very same time. This would not be a issue in the past because Access would produce an error regarding the duplicate IDs and the application would detect the error and simply execute Max(ID) +1 again. But with no primary key, two child records would be saved with the same ID. And later, if any of the users made a change to one of those records, then both records would be updated and all fields for both (including the foreign key for the parent, parentID) would be set to identical values. This would then result in one parent having no children, and another parent having duplicate children. My goodness what a mess!!

I just tried adding the primary key to the table and I can't because there are duplicate records which I must find and delete. I'll post the final result as an answer after I'm able to add the primary key back. Thanks for all your help.

---

Now one last note: the table in question is the largest in the database, containing well over 3.5 million records. The table has 22 fields, 20 of which are long integers, one is a text field with a field size of 100. The other a Boolean field.

**What I've Done**

Since the application hasn't changed, I immediately assumed (and continue to assume) that the problem is corruption in the MS Access Database. I have done the following:

1. Compact the database every day
2. Create a fresh database and import the tables from the old database to the new one.
3. Create a new database and import only the definition of the tables, one at a time, then use Append Queries to get the data over to the new database.
4. Made sure I got latest service packs for Office
5. Made sure connection objects and recordsets are properly closed/disposed of
6. Contemplated suicide
7. Read and implemented suggestions detailed by a Microsoft article about how to keep a Jet database in top working order.

I'll also go over the application with a fine comb to see if I find anything, though everything points to Access being the culprit

**Any Ideas?**

Has anyone been in a situation like this before? I myself had a a similar issue with the same database about 10 years ago. Back then, I was getting the "Unrecognizable file format" error which was a clear case of database corruption. I fixed it by creating a new database and importing the tables, but that hasn't helped this time. Any ideas?

Comment: In (1), is there a runtime error thrown? What is its number and description? (2) I don't understand, can you revise that part?

Comment: (1) What is 'timeNotExpired'? (2) I would create an 'error' table to log every error encountered -- just in case a user has the habit of ignoring an error. (3) I assume what you call 'primary key' doesn't allow dups, and the 'dup records' actually have different ID's? (4) I would convert the sql commands to use RS.Addnew / RS.Edit - you may not receive notification of edit failure (i.e. RecordsAffected = 0);

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys, and sorry for the confusion

1. Although not shown in the error Err_Handler above, the application logs every error that occurs during a save operation. Errors are saved to a text file. They're very rare and they're usually due to Max(ID) + 1 returning the same ID to more than one user. When an error occurs, it's invisible from the user because the application executes Max(ID) + 1 again. The only time the user sees an error is if the save operation fails, at which case a Connection.RollbackTrans is executed and absolutely nothing is saved to the database.

Comment: Andre451 2 - I'll update the question to clarify #2. @WayneG.Dunn 1 - I keep looping for a specific time in an effort to save the record again. After a while, I stop and display an error. But this absolutely never ever ever happens. Saving is always successful. (3) No duplicates are allowed. Executing Max(ID) + 1 at the time from multiple computer would cause duplicate, in which case there is an error which the user never sees (but it's logged) as it's resolved right there. 4. This app has been working as explained above for about 12 years. I'll try that :(

Comment: *(2) a given record in that same table would be the application would 2 or even 3 times* still doesn't make sense... -- Perhaps you should post your actual (complete) code for saving, maybe we spot a problem. It doesn't really sound like database corruption to me.

Comment: @Andre451 Thanks again. Please read the second Edit to my question.  The application code hasnt' been updated so it isn't the source of the problem. The issue is that for some obscure reason, the primary key from that child table was deleted. The duplicate/missing records started popping up last week Tuesday or so, right in the middle of the work day while people were using the application, which is why database corruption was my only explanation.

Comment: A missing key is a sure sign of corruption. I have seen it before. You should also check for autonumbers that need to be re-seeded, any other missing indexes or relationships. Then look for causes of corruption. You'll find a ton of info on that with a simple web search. You mention the number of rows in a table, but the important thing is the size of the data file. What is the size?

Comment: Thanks @AVG. It is indeed database corruption and I've followed Microsoft's advice on "How to keep a Microsoft Jet Database in Top Working Order" so I'm not sure there's much more I can do to prevent the corruption anymore. Now the database has been working fine for over 12 years and I have seen corruption only once before, about 10 years ago. 

I'll review all indexes/relationships as well to make sure they're all in working order. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue stemmed from the fact that Microsoft Access dropped the primary keys of two tables on the database. Because I use `Max(ID) + 1` to obtain the ID for new records, and there are multiple users creating new records at once, the same ID was sometimes used for more than one record. This caused the issues mentioned above.

To solve the problem, I simply added the keys back after deleting any duplicate entries I found.

I'll also try to stay clear of `Max(ID) + 1` for new records as suggested by @DanielG.

If anyone else is unlucky enough to be working with MS Access in a multi-user environment, I suggest following Microsoft's suggestions outlined in the article [How to keep a Jet 4.0 database in top working condition](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303528).

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: We had a FE/BE arrangement at 75 sites around the world, and I encountered this same 'random' issue with keys being dropped - and sometimes table relationships. Since we already had a nightly VB program that ran on the server, I added code to validate the presence of each index and restore if required. Of course I spent lots of time trying to find the culprit but eventually gave up, relied on the code to fix, and moved on to the next brain-teaser....

Answer (score 0):

I would check the data type of the ID column, and make sure it is large enough. Consider changing it to a counter data type instead of running a domain function (MAX(ID)), or a replicationID if possible. That's where your issue may be happening.

I've set the ID to LONG before, and maintained my own counter in another table. Maybe a table that holds the NextID column, and a VBA function that gets this and updates + 1 for the next guy. Within a transaction this can be more reliable than MAX, which has to contend with locks.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the suggestion. The data type of ID is Long so it has space for over 2 billion records (table only has 3.5 million records so we're ok in terms of space). We didn't use an AutoIncrement field for it because Access/VB6 don't have a reliable way (that I know of, at least) to retrieve the ID of the last record inserted to update the objects after they're saved. Now, I'm not sure I follow how Max(ID) would be the source of the problem, though? Can you please elaborate? Max(ID) + 1 does return duplicates sometimes but the application already deals with that case.

Comment: Good morning, Leon. MAX(ID) get progressively slower over time and can be subject to conflicts with simultaneous inserts/updates. I would take the approach of creating another table like tblCounters, with a field called CounterType and NextValue. Create a VBA function that grabs the NextCounter and increments it by one. You can then use this counter for all inserts, including related records. It is basically your own counter, but you can wrap the function that gets the next value into a transaction. So at the top of your code, call the function, get a value, and use it for all inserts.

Comment: Thanks @DanielG. I don't believe Max(ID) was the cause of my problem in this particular case, but your alternative method for getting IDs for new records sounds pretty sweet. I'll look into implementing it in my application. Cheers.